# How prevent input boarder appearing on click with react?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a react app with an input. I styled it so it has only the bottom border perfectly as I want. When I click on it, the black border appears. How could I fix it and make it stay clear even when I click on it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide 0(zero) to  `outline-width` to disable appearing border.

```css
input {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter something" />
```

Comment: @ДаняЛяторовский if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this. Happy coding!